# Using stored procedures to simplify XML generation

Tags: sql-server, xml, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I am trying to write an SP to return invoice details in XML for transferring to a third party.

I have a working SP but it's a bit messy (simplified below):

```
SELECT ( 
    SELECT GETDATE() AS HEADER_SLAStartTime
         , DATEADD(HOUR, @SLA_HOURS, GETDATE()) AS HEADER_SLAEndTime
    FOR XML PATH ('Header'), TYPE

    ) , (

        SELECT ACCT AS CustomerCode
             , ACCTNAME As CustomerName
             , ADDR#1 As AddressLine1
             , ADDR#2 AS AddressLine2
             , ADDR#3 AS AddressLine3
             , ADDR#4 AS AddressLine4
             , POSTCODE AS AddressPostcode
             , TELNO AS AddressTelno

        FROM InvHdr

        WHERE INVNO = @INVNO

        FOR XML PATH('Customer'), TYPE

    ) , (

        SELECT (
            SELECT INVNO AS InvoiceNo
                 , [DATE] AS InvoiceDate
                 , [INVTYPE] AS InvoiceType
                 , CASE [SOURCE] WHEN 0 THEN 'Contract' WHEN 1 THEN 'Manual' WHEN 2 THEN 'Sales Order' ELSE '' END AS InvoiceSourceText
                 , THEIRREF AS CustomerReference
                 , YOURREF AS InternalReference
                 , (
                    SELECT ITEMNO AS ItemCode
                         , [ITEMDESC#1] AS ItemDesc
                         , [TYPE] AS ItemType
                         , [MEMO] AS ItemMemo
                         , [GOODS] AS ItemCharge
                         , [DISCOUNT] AS ItemDiscount

                    FROM InvItems

                    WHERE INVNO = HDR.INVNO

                    FOR XML PATH('InvItem'), TYPE
                    )

            FROM InvHdr HDR

            WHERE INVNO = @INVNO

            FOR XML PATH('InvoiceHeader'), TYPE

        ) , (

            SELECT HDR.[GOODS] AS InvoiceNet
                 , HDR.VAT AS InvoiceVAT
                 , HDR.[GOODS] + HDR.VAT AS InvoiceGross
                 , (

                    SELECT VATCODE AS VATListCode
                         , VATAMT AS VATListAmount
                         , VATDESC AS VATListDescription
                         , VATRATE AS VATListRate
                         , VATGOODS AS VATListGoods

                    FROM InvVAT

                    WHERE InvVAT.INVNO = HDR.INVNO

                    ORDER BY VATAMT DESC

                    FOR XML PATH('VATSummary'), TYPE
                   )
            FROM InvHdr HDR

            WHERE INVNO = @INVNO

            FOR XML PATH('InvoiceFooter'), TYPE
        )
        FOR XML PATH('Invoices'), TYPE


    )
FOR XML PATH(''), ROOT('Output')
```

This procedure works but I have to create lots of these to get different bits of information in different orders, I have tried creating separate SP's to get the data in sections, below is my first section SP:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE UDEF_DC_XML_INVOICEFOOTER(
    @INVNO INT
    )

AS

BEGIN


    SELECT HDR.[GOODS] AS InvoiceNet
         , HDR.VAT AS InvoiceVAT
         , HDR.[GOODS] + HDR.VAT AS InvoiceGross
         , (

            SELECT VATCODE AS VATListCode
                 , VATAMT AS VATListAmount
                 , VATDESC AS VATListDescription
                 , VATRATE AS VATListRate
                 , VATGOODS AS VATListGoods

            FROM InvVAT

            WHERE InvVAT.INVNO = HDR.INVNO

            ORDER BY VATAMT DESC

            FOR XML PATH('VATSummary'), TYPE
           )
    FROM InvHdr HDR

    WHERE INVNO = @INVNO

    FOR XML PATH('InvoiceFooter'), TYPE


END
```

When I try calling this:

```
SELECT UDEF_DC_XML_INVOICEFOOTER(@INVNO)
FOR XML PATH('Invoices'), TYPE
```

I get the error:

```
Msg 4121, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Cannot find either column "dbo" or the user-defined function or aggregate "dbo.UDEF_DC_XML_INVOICEFOOTER", or the name is ambiguous.
```

In the end I'm hoping to be able to create multiple 4/5 line SP's that will call all the sections in the correct order. Either via calling the individual SP's in order or writing each section to variables and building the full XML afterwards.

Is it possible to call multiple stored procedures returning XML within a single statement?

Comment: "Using stored procedures to simplify XML generation" - isn't that a contradiction of terms?!?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it possible to call multiple stored procedures returning XML within
>   a single statement?

No, but you can use functions that return XML.

```sql
create function dbo.GetXML(@Value int) returns xml
as
begin
  return (
         select @Value as X
         for xml path('Y'), type
         )
end
```

Use like this:

```sql
select dbo.GetXML(1)
for xml path('Z')
```

Result:

```xml
<Z>
  <Y>
    <X>1</X>
  </Y>
</Z>
```

Comment: That looks ideal, can you nest the function calls to generate nested XML?

Comment: Perfect, appreciate your help!